# Pros and Cons of Samba and Windows as fileserver

Tags: windows, samba, file-server, samba4

Beyond the licenses of each one of them: what are the benefits and cons that have both Samba (Linux) and MS Windows as fileserver?

Comment: Please refer to advantages of UNIX over Windows. please google: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41705/advantage-to-using-linux-over-windows

Answer (score 1):

Platform choice is probably the big criteria. You get access to a lot more file systems than on Windows. You also have access to a more exhaustive set of tunables, should you be interested in going that route. Some people also prefer the Linux firewall to the Windows one.

There are also a lot of widely used tools in the Linux world that have niche commercial analogs in the Windows one. For instance, if you wanted to get block device encryption going, Windows doesn't support that out of the box. It's available but you have to pay for it ([Symantec](https://www.symantec.com/endpoint-encryption/) for instance). Even after you pay for it there are going to only be so many people who have experience dealing with that tool versus their competitors. That's just one example there are plenty more. Basically, ISV's based on FOSS have to give their product away (well don't *have* to but it's in their interests) which leads to more people using it and having enough experience with it to help you should you get into an issue.

You also benefit from running a hybrid environment meaning that someone has to possess advanced knowledge of each platform in order to compromise your network.

For example, just because they know how to exploit Linux servers, doesn't mean they're going to be able to pollute the shares in some way that can then leave your Windows desktops vulnerable. It also works the other way, where if they do pollute the shares by hijacking some session, then server controls can try to contain the compromise to just that one share. That's not fool proof but it does pose another obstacle an attacker has to overcome.